# windows wget & being cut off

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command, wget

System Info:
Windows 7,
GNU Wget 1.11.4,
Python 2.6

The problem:

Im running a python script that fires a wget shortcut, the problem is that wget (even when run purely in command line from the exe) cuts off '&''s. For example when i run the code below, this is what i get:

> C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>wget.exe
> http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action&sort=alpha,asc&start=51&title_type=feature
>
> SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc syswgetrc = C:\Program
> Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
>
> --2013-01-18 12:48:43--  http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action Resolving
> www.imdb.com... 72.21.215.52 Connecting to
> www.imdb.com|72.21.215.52|:80... failed: Connection refused.
>
> =alpha,ascThe system cannot find the file specified.
>
> The system cannot find the file 51. 'title_type' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command,  operable program or batch file.

As you can see, wget counts all text before the '&' as the URL in question, and windows take the last half as a new command(s).

There has got to be some way of allowing wget to capture that whole string as the URL.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
When i call the command in command line with brackets around it, it works great, however, when i run the script through python:

```
subprocess.Popen(['start /B wget.lnk --directory-prefix=' + output_folder + ' --output-document=' + output_folder + 'this.html "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action&sort=alpha,asc&start=51&title_type=feature"'], shell=True)
```

I get the following error:

> SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
>
> syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
>
> "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action&sort=alpha,asc&start=51&title_ty
> pe=feature": Unsupported scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Wget that cuts off the URL, but the command interpreter, which uses `&` to separate two commands, akin to `;`. This is indicated by the `=alpha,ascThe system cannot find the file specified.` error on the following line.

To prevent this from happening, quote the entire URL:

```
wget.exe "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action&sort=alpha,asc&start=51&title_type=feature"
```